# Why class can not be referred from within the class as a Data-attributes?

Tags: python-3.x

```
class A(object):
    def __nikunj__(self):
        print("Inside :: A")
    def __nike__(self):
        print("Something")

class B(A):

    def __nike__(self):
        print("inside :: B")
        super(B,self).__nike__()


object_B = B()
print(object_B.__nike__())
```

Above code works fine.

```
class A(object):
    def __nikunj__(self):
        print("Inside :: A")
    def __nike__(self):
        print("Something")

class B(A):
    test = super(B,self).__nike__()
    def __nike__(self):
        print("inside :: B")



object_B = B()
print(object_B.test)
```

This code throws Error :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Nikunj Parmar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36               \test_test.py", line 7, in <module>
    class B(A):
    File "C:\Users\Nikunj Parmar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\test_test.py", line 8, in B
    test = super(B,self).__nike__()
    NameError: name 'B' is not defined
```

Why? I don't understand why it shows that B is not found (in second case).

Comment: Why are you using dunder methods with non-standard names? That's technically not allowed.

Comment: "Above code works fine.": Show the actual output.

Comment: @MadPhysicist It doesn't. excepted output is None.

Comment: I beg to differ, the code is expected to print two lines, then None.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thank you for your help.

Comment: You may find this helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods

Comment: @HeenashreeKhandelwal. Judging from this question, OP has a pretty good understanding of `super`, and just wants an explanation of how the namespaces and scope work out in a class definition. How is your link relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the class body is being evaluated, the class object has not been created yet.

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-definition-syntax):

> When a class definition is entered, a new namespace is created, and used as the local scope — thus, all assignments to local variables go into this new namespace. In particular, function definitions bind the name of the new function here.
>
> When a class definition is left normally (via the end), a class *object* is created. This is basically a wrapper around the contents of the namespace created by the class definition; we’ll learn more about class objects in the next section. The original local scope (the one in effect just before the class definition was entered) is reinstated, and the class object is bound here to the class name given in the class definition header (`ClassName` in the example).

You may want to read that [whole page](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html). It explains exactly how the namespace of a class works, and when things get created.

The first version works because of [LEGB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/292502/2988730) evaluation. Your method code is evaluated but *not* called when the method is defined. Using `B` within a method compiles to "find name B". The name does not have to exist until you actually call the method. When you do finally execute the code, the names `A` and `B` are already bound to classes in the global namespace (the G in LEGB), and everything works out fine.

Finally, keep in mind that using double underscore (dunder) methods (a.k.a. [special methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) or magic methods) is extremely frowned upon in Python. These methods serve the purpose of operator overloading, and all such names are automatically reserved. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers):

> *Any* use of `__*__` names, in any context, that does not follow explicitly documented use, is subject to breakage without warning.

Since you are new to Python, I have attempted to post some links for you to follow, as well as mentioning some basic concepts that are pretty ubiquitous in the language. Hope that helps you in the future.

Answer (score 1):

1. Methods are called (ie executed) after an object exists (ie the class itself or an instance of it).

   In the 1<sup>st</sup> example by the time `__nike__` is called the `B` class is already defined. Statements in a class body are executed when in the class's definition time. In the 2<sup>nd</sup> example, by the time `test = super(B,self).__nike__()` is executed there is no such thing as class `B` since this line is executed when the class is defined for the very first time.

   The same behavior can be observed in the following line: `d = {'a': 1, 'b': d['a']}`.
   This results with `NameError: name 'd' is not defined` since `d` is not yet defined when we attempt to access `d['a']`.
2. Don't use dunder names for arbitrary methods.